# Response URI for Azure AD B2C returns 404, custom OpenID identity provider

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, openid-provider

We're implementing a custom identity provider for Azure AD B2C, using OpenID protocol option, as a generic OpenID Connect.

Everything works as expected until it's time to post the response back to Azure AD B2C using the redirect URI provided. I've found documentation regarding expected structure of this response URL, and what we see in the documentation is identical to what Azure AD B2C specifies when it issues the authentication sequence.

Configured values:
Response type: code
Response mode: form_post
User ID claim: sub
Display name claim: name

When the custom identity provider GETs or POSTs authentication response (code) back to https://REDACTED.b2clogin.com/REDACTED.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp, the Azure B2C returns 404.

Note that this is not 400, not 401, not 403, not 5xx. It is precisely 404 (not found), with a basic text (non-html) content saying resource not found. This response looks to me very much like a misconfigured API management layer on Azure side, hitting a wrong internal URL.

We're expecting that the URL https://REDACTED.b2clogin.com/REDACTED.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp actually works. It looks like what the expected Azure AD B2C response endpoint is from documentation, and it is also exactly what Azure AD B2C itself specifies when initiating the OpenID sequence with our custom identity provider web application.

So far we were unable to find the root cause, nor even any useful input beyond raw network request logs (case with Microsoft support was open since 2023-01-23). The last resort could be re-creating the B2C tenant, since this feature seems to work for other people, but that would require migration and significant down time on our end.

**SOLUTION: The response to AD B2C authresp endpoint was missing 'nonce' claim (in the id_token payload), and 'state' parameter in the HTTP request.** Both values are supplied by AD B2C when initiating authorization. As soon as custom identity provider started properly adding those two values, error 404 went away.

Comment: For me the redirect URI `https://myb2ctenant.b2clogin.com/myb2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp` works with Azure AD setup as an OpenID Connect identity provider.

Comment: I suspect this could be caused by the recent migration we were doing with the resources in adjacent subscription. However whatever that is, it would be great to have a way to positively confirm the cause.

Comment: Can you not open a case with Microsoft?

Comment: The case with Microsoft was open since couple weeks ago, and plenty interaction happened there. Unfortunately the support so far didn't go anywhere past collecting raw input such as network traces, screenshots, repros, and live screenshares.

Comment: Just to confirm: You do have the correct policy name in the response URL in your traces? So `authresp?p=B2C_1...`. Because if the policy name is missing or incorrect, you can immediately get this 404 error. This is why we use the policy as part of the path `https://myb2ctenant.b2clogin.com/myb2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1a_signin/oauth2/authresp` with our custom openID provider, it has much less issues.

Comment: We don't have the policy name in the response URI. I am going to try inserting the policy name now to see if this helps.

Comment: To clarify, the documentation says the policy name should only be in the initiation request to B2C itself, and the redirect_uri parameter sent to our custom IdP app does not have the policy name. I will try it now anyway.

Comment: Tried four options: 1) adding policy name immediately before /oauth2/authresp in original mixed case policy name, 2) same as #1 but all lowercase, 3) adding policy name as query string ?p=XXXX in original mixed case while using POST method, 4) same as #3 but using GET method so "code" goes into query string too. All end up with a generic "An exception occurred" returned to client app, and "The service received a bad request" error in the B2C Audit Log. P.S: I didn't just switch POST to GET - also adjusted the setting in the Idp settings.

Comment: BTW Azure support notified us that our request made it to the product dev group, so keeping fingers crossed someone there will give us an authoritative answer.

Comment: At least those "exception occured" indicate to me that you are closer to succeeding. We have it working with IdentityServer with the policy in the path. Not sure how I could help further. Will be interested to hear if it gets finally resolved, good luck.

Comment: Right. I've tried injecting the policy name into the response URI very early in the development phase, got into the same situation and abandoned it. Looks like it makes sense to dig further into troubleshooting using this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Response should include supplied nonce as a claim inside the id_token payload, and supplied state as HTTP request parameter or query string**

https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-basic-1_0.html

I had the same issue (a 404 error as a result of the /authresp POST from my custom OIDC IdP back to Azure AD B2C using the redirect URI Azure AD B2C had just provided as a query parameter on the /authorize request to my IdP: `redirect_uri=https://mytenant.b2login.com/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp`

In my case (using an implicit flow), it was about properly handling the "nonce" query parameter on the inbound /authorize request (from Azure AD B2C to my IdP) by ensuring the generated id_token it returned included the nonce as a claim.

In your case (using an authorization code flow...and assuming you also return an id_token based on the "sub" and "name" claims you're returning), your /token endpoint needs to include the nonce inside the id_token...so propagate the nonce (and state) as query parameters along to your /token endpoint via the /authorize to /token redirect method you use.

***If a federated IdP doesn't include the nonce as a claim inside the id_token payload that it returns, Azure AD B2C will return a 404 error from the /authresp request.***

I don't know why Microsoft chose to return a 404 instead of a more informative "nonce invalid" error message, or at least, a 400 error...perhaps it's for the same security reason a login form doesn't precisely tell you when your password is invalid.

In the OpenID Connect specification, the nonce description (under [IDToken](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDToken)) states (bolding is my doing):

> String value used to associate a Client session with an ID Token, and to mitigate replay attacks. The value is passed through unmodified from the Authentication Request to the ID Token. If present in the ID Token, Clients MUST verify that the nonce Claim Value is equal to the value of the nonce parameter sent in the Authentication Request. **If present in the Authentication Request, Authorization Servers MUST include a nonce Claim in the ID Token with the Claim Value being the nonce value sent in the Authentication Request.** Authorization Servers SHOULD perform no other processing on nonce values used. The nonce value is a case sensitive string.

Although the spec indicates a nonce is optional, Microsoft is following best practices by supplying one...and since Azure AD B2C (as the Authorization Server) gets the id_token from the IdP, it requires a federated OIDC IdP to play by the same rule.

In case this helps others, my custom IdP's /.well-known/openid-configuration endpoint returns:

```
 {
  "authorization_endpoint": "https://myidp.azurewebsites.net/oauth2/authorize",
  "authorization_response_iss_parameter_supported": true,
  "claims_parameter_supported": false,
  "claims_supported": [
    "aud",
    "idp",
    "iss",
    "iat",
    "exp",
    "nonce",
    "s-hash",
    "sid",
    "sub",
    "auth_time",
    "email",
    "family_name",
    "given_name",
    "locale",
    "name",
    "updated_at",
    "user_id"
  ],
  "claim_types_supported": ["normal"],
  "grant_types_supported": ["implicit"],
  "id_token_signing_alg_values_supported": ["RS256"],
  "issuer": "https://myidp.azurewebsites.net",
  "jwks_uri": "https://myidp.azurewebsites.net/oauth2/jwks",
  "response_modes_supported": ["form_post"],
  "response_types_supported": ["id_token"],
  "scopes_supported": ["openid"]
}
```

(Yes, my IdP runs on an Azure App server...but, "myidp" isn't my real tenant name.)

p.s. Currently, my IdP is used exclusively in a federation with AzureAD B2C (which acts as the Authorization Server for my client application via the MSAL library), so my IdP simply supports just an implicit flow and three endpoints (/.well-known/openid-configuration, /jwks and /authorize).  If it were a general purpose IdP, or allowed direct client requests, it would support other flows (e.g. an authorization code flow), additional scopes (beyond "openid"...e.g. "profile") and additional endpoints (e.g. /token and /userinfo).  However, regardless of flow, as long as an id_token is returned, it needs to include the nonce in its payload.

Comment: Going to diagnose the token content now. I have also verified that a different instance of B2C returns the same 404 with my custom IdP, so my custom IdP is likely to be the cause.

Comment: So you were right to suggest that my id_token did not have a nonce claim. Unfortunately, having modified the endpoint to include the nonce claim into the token payload, B2C authresp still returns 404. The response posted to B2C contains the only parameter "id_token", and request content type is 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'. Can you maybe attach the full list of claim names your custom IDP includes into the id_token? P.S.: this solution is also intended exclusively for integration with B2C.

Comment: Okay, so the last missing piece was the missing state parameter. B2C supplies it with authorization request. As soon as I had both nonce and state returned properly, 404 got away.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help!...and thanks for the extra insight on "state".   I just ran another test and can  reaffirm that returning the state is mandatory too (otherwise, you'll get a 404).  The nonce goes in the id_token, but the state is returned as a query parameter (one could include an s_hash claim into the id_token - which is a hash of the state - but I don't include that claim in my id_token).

Comment: Yes, big thanks for your hint, the solution is now complete. BTW Azure support is still dangling and pulling the time - and we're using a paid tier. I wonder if they will ever come with any meaningful recommendation on our ticket, and luckily, we don't care if they will anymore.

Answer (score -1):

***I tried to reproduce the scenario in my environment:***
Make sure  the endpoint to which I requested the authorization url

It includes policy and  with
***redirect URI= `https://kavyasarabojub2c.b2clogin.com/kavyasarabojub2c.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp`***

***User Flow is of SignupSignin and not just Signin***

[image]

Make sure to include all the required **api permissions** , importantly make sure to include `openid , profile`

[image]

I Configure idp such that , userId is mapped to oid.

[image]

The authorization url must have the policy included .

Here I have **B2C_1_SignupSignin** policy set for the User flow.

redirect URI= **`https://kavyasarabojub2c.b2clogin.com/kavyasarabojub2c.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp`**

Auth url:

https://kavyasarabojub2c.b2clogin.com/kavyasarabojub2c.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_newSignupSignin&client_id=xxx&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fxxxb2c.b2clogin.com%2Fxxxb2c.onmicrosoft.com%2Foauth2%2Fauthresp&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login

When profile scope is not given I got bad request

[image]

But when `openid` and `profile` along with `Directory.Read.All` api permissions are included, the request run successfully.

**Note:** metadata url must be : ***`https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantId>/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration`***

[image]

***Successfully logged in and got the token containing idp_access_token***
[image]

[image]

***Identity provider access token , decoded and  got the user claims:***
[image]

Comment: Thank you for a detailed repro. Unfortunately it's not relevant to our case, since the error is 404, not 400. I believe other data points match your scenario. https://REDACTED.b2clogin.com/REDACTED.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_sing-in-up-dev&client_id=REDACTED&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=REDACTED&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login

Comment: @Roman Polunin Can you provide the logs of the error 404 that you got and few more details like firewall issue or something to investigate as i did not face 404 error with given redirects.

Comment: Kavya, the detailed traces contain some relatively sensitive information which I would have to carefully scrub before posting here. I hoped to see an answer that would point me towards the way to troubleshoot this 404 on the authresp endpoint myself, or while doing it with MS support live. I do not expect SO users to be able to give me a precise response.